# How broken is a xor of two multiply with carry generators?

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator

- [How broken is a xor of two LCGs?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10526/how-broken-is-a-xor-of-two-lcgs)
- [How Brittle Are LCG-Cracking Techniques?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-brittle-are-lcg-cracking-techniques)

Based on the above two questions, I have simply one additional question: how broken is a XOR of two 64-bit multiply with carry generators, with one generator's output rotated by 24-bits before the XOR, and independently generated seed states, with the first output discarded?

Furthermore, what is the fastest attack against this generator with only $2^{20}$ outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to expect your construction to be cryptographically secure.  A single MWC generator is not something that was ever designed to be cryptographically secure.  A cryptographically-strong PRNG needs to be designed in a very different way from a non-crypto PRNG.  In particular, it sounds like MWC was designed to have a long period.  But having a long period does not guarantee that a PRNG will be crypto-strength; not anywhere near it.  And xor-ing two non-crypto-strength PRNGs is not in general a good way to build a crypto-strength PRNG; there's no reason to expect that such a scheme will be secure.

Crypto-strength PRNGs have much stronger requirements, so there is no reason to expect that a statistical non-crypto PRNG will be cryptographically strong (it almost certainly won't be, if it wasn't designed to be).  If you want a crypto-strength PRNG, you need to pick one that was designed to be that way from the start; you're not likely to fare well by picking a non-crypto PRNG and then trying to tweak it.

In any case, this approach seems misguided.  We have crypto-strength PRNGs that are secure, fast, and well-vetted.  I don't know why one would mess around with trying to design your own based upon a non-crypto PRNG; that way tends to lead to insecurity.  If you think you can do better than the entire field at designing fast crypto-strength PRNGs... well, maybe you can, but I doubt the odds are on your side.  Instead, I recommend you use a standard crypto-strength PRNG, if you need crypto-quality pseudorandom numbers.

I recommend take a look at [What stops the Multiply-With-Carry RNG from being a Cryptographically Secure PRNG?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10359/351), as well as by [KISS: A Bit Too Simple](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007) (PDF).  The first one handles the plain MWC construction by Marsaglia; the later analyzes the non-cryptographic scheme by Marsaglia named KISS (which combines the output from two MWC generators as well as a linear congruential generator and a  binary linear generator).  Both do not exactly represent the same construction, but the broad lessons probably apply here as well.  I've paraphrased from [my answer there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10366/12164) and extended it to apply to this specific question as well.